# using a simple tabhost in android along with buttons

Tags: android, android-tabhost

### I have placed a set of horizontal buttons on top of the tab

- **But i have a gap between them**
- **how can i remove the gap between them,**
- alignment is not properly done ! ..... how to perform this action ?

Any ideas on doing it

**screen_topbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="List" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Photo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Map" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Filter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/screen_topbar" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/screen_bottombar" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Define height width to include?

Comment: please look at the updated question

Comment: Set height to match_parent of all button.

Comment: @ Jitesh Dalsaniya ..... that worked thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

**screen_topbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="4dip" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="List" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Photo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Map" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="Filter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And **main.xml**

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/screen_topbar" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```